# Hibernate, writing domain objects to an interface for lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate

Why does hibernate require it's entities to be written to an interface in order for them to work correctly with lazy loading?

Comment: btw, I assumed you mean collection interfaces

Comment: Ah, I mean writing a domain object / peristent entity too an interface rather than a concrete implementation

Comment: hibernate has no requirement for that.

Comment: I was under the impression that when you access a lazily loaded entity, you have problems with instanceof and casting on the proxy unless the target domain object was written to an interface, but I am confused as to why this is.

Comment: what do you mean by "lazily loaded entity" ? Hiberante has lazy loading for associations. Is it a lazy @ManyToOne? Why do you think it requires an interface?

Comment: An entity (object which maps to a database record) when lazily loaded will be a proxy, which doesn't go to the database until I try and access data from it.  This proxy from what I am aware, is a dynamically created subclass of the superclass of the original entity.  Because of this behaviour, things such getClass will return the class of the proxy, and casting will not work unless casting to the superclass.  I have been told that writing domain objects to an interface should help with these problems, but I am unsure as to why this is.  Have I been given bogus information?

Comment: that is used very rarely. And even when it is, you should not use getClass(). Using an interface is redundant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only scenario where hibernate requires interfaces is collections. It's because hibernate uses its own collection implementations for lazy loading - `PersistentBag`, `PersistentSet`, etc. and assigns them to your fields. The implementations hold a reference to the session so that they can fill their data whenever required.

Hibernate can assign `PersistentSet` to `private Set<Foo> set;` (they do it with reflection), but it is not possible to do so for `private HashSet<Foo> set;`, because `PersistentSet` does not extend `HashSet`

As for lazy `@*ToOne` associations - hibernate creates a proxy object, using javassist (or cglib), and it does not require an interface. This is a rarely used feature anyway, and the proxy is a subclass of the real object, so unless you use `getclass()` (which you should not do), it works fine.